# Problemas con conexion bluetooth android studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Estoy tratando de realizar una aplicación que se conecte a un módulo Bluetooth y posteriormente poder navegar entre distintas *activities* conectado al módulo.

El problema es que la conexión en la *activity* principal está bien pero cuando lanzo otra *activity* se pierde la conexión.

¿Alguna idea de cómo podría mantener la conexión activa o de cómo volver a reconectar en la *activity* nueva?

Éste es mi código:

```
public class Pantalla_Principal extends AppCompatActivity {


    Handler bluetoothIn;
    final int handlerState = 0;
    TextView CajaDeInformacion = null;

    Button BotonPruebaDeConexion, BotonConfigurar, BotonSeleccionar, BotonEliminar, BotonSalir;


    public StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();
    public Pantalla_Principal.ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    public static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    public static String address;
    public static String Dispositivo;
    BluetoothDevice device;
    BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;

    public static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pantalla__principal);


        final Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        address = intent.getStringExtra(Pantalla_Conexion.EXTRA_ADDRESS);



        CajaDeInformacion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CajaDePruebas);
        BotonConfigurar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BotonConfigurar);
        BotonSeleccionar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BotonSeleccionar);
        BotonEliminar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BotonEliminar);
        BotonPruebaDeConexion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BotonPruebaDeConexion);
        BotonSalir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BotonSalir);

        BotonPruebaDeConexion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (btSocket != null) {
                    try {
                        btSocket.getOutputStream().write("Hola".toString().getBytes());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Mensaje("Error");
                    }
                }

            }
        });


        BotonConfigurar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent PantallaConfigurar = new Intent(Pantalla_Principal.this, Pantalla_Configuracion.class);


                startActivity(PantallaConfigurar);
                finish();


            }
        });

        BotonSeleccionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent PantallaTelevisores = new Intent(Pantalla_Principal.this, Plantilla_Televisores.class);
                PantallaTelevisores.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
                PantallaTelevisores.putExtra(Dispositivo,device);
                //PantallaTelevisores.putExtra("Dispositivo",device)
                startActivity(PantallaTelevisores);



            }
        });


        BotonSalir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (btSocket != null) {
                    try {
                        Mensaje("Conexion Finalizada");
                        btSocket.close();
                        finish();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Mensaje("Error");
                    }
                }

            }
        });


        this.bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == 0) {

                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                    Pantalla_Principal.this.recDataString.append(readMessage);
                    Pantalla_Principal.this.CajaDeInformacion.setText("   ");
                    Pantalla_Principal.this.CajaDeInformacion.setText(recDataString);


                }
            }
        };


        this.myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        this.checkBTState();

    }

    public BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
    }

    private void Mensaje(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        BluetoothDevice device = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);
        try {
            this.btSocket = this.createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException var7) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", 1).show();
        }

        try {
            this.btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException var6) {
            try {

                this.btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException var5) {
                ;
            }
        }

        this.mConnectedThread = new Pantalla_Principal.ConnectedThread(this.btSocket);
        this.mConnectedThread.start();

    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        try {
            this.btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException var2) {
            ;
        }

    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            this.btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException var2) {
            ;
        }
    }

    public void checkBTState() {
        if (this.myBluetooth == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Device does not support bluetooth", 1).show();
        } else if (!this.myBluetooth.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent("android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE");
            this.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }

    }

    public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException var6) {
                ;
            }

            this.mmInStream = tmpIn;
            this.mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

            while (true) {
                try {
                    int bytes = this.mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Pantalla_Principal.this.bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(0, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException var4) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si te fijas en el [ciclo de vida de una actividad en Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html), existen dos pasos importantes: `onResume` y `onPause`.

Cuando una actividad se encuentra en el estado `Resumed`, está en primer plano, con lo que el usuario puede interactuar con ella.

Cuando una actividad se encuentra en estado Paused, podríamos decir que dicha actividad no está en primer plano, sino que hay otra actividad que está activa.

Si te fijas en tu implementación:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    BluetoothDevice device = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);
    try {
        this.btSocket = this.createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException var7) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", 1).show();
    }

    try {
        this.btSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException var6) {
        try {

            this.btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException var5) {
            ;
        }
    }

    this.mConnectedThread = new Pantalla_Principal.ConnectedThread(this.btSocket);
    this.mConnectedThread.start();

}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    try {
        this.btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException var2) {
        ;
    }

}
```

En el paso `onResume` inicias la conexión bluetooth

```
this.btSocket = this.createBluetoothSocket(device);
```

Y en el paso `onPause` la cierras.

```
this.btSocket.close();
```

Por lo que en otra actividad podrías crear estos dos pasos para utilizar la conexión. Sin embargo, mi recomendación es que independices la conexión de las actividades, por ejemplo utilizando un Servicio Android.